# Search names case insensitive bug

Tags: javascript, html, search, names

```js
function Search_Name() {
  let input, filter, table, i;
  input = document.getElementById("Name");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("Entries");
  td = table.getElementsByTagName("td");
    
  for(i = 0; i < IDInc; i++) {
    txtValue = td[i].innerText;
                
    if(txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) 
      td[i].style.display = "";
    else 
      td[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

I tried this javascript code to search for names case insensitive only to get buggy/unstable results.

How to fix it?

And thanks.

(Note: IDInc is the length of the Names array; ID is just the the position of names in array and not necessary for the search function)

Comment: Could you provide an example of the results you were getting?

Comment: Why don't you use `td.length`?

Comment: What is the `Names` array, and how is it related to this? Why do you use its length as the limit of the loop?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Nevermind about the names (or NameID as it's called) array; I used it in my JS file to build the table and does so. But when I try to grab the table from HTML for filtering, it just bugs frequently.

Comment: I didn't use the td.length since I already grabbed the length from the NameID array itself

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mustdos/0a2htnp8/3/